# '>' is an unexpected token. The expected token is '"' or '''. Line 1, position 55

Tags: c#, api

Below is the code . Trying to call a rest api but receiving the above error of unexpected token.

```
 public static class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Uri baseUrl = new Uri("https://httpbin.org/");
            IRestClient client = new RestClient(baseUrl);
            IRestRequest request = new RestRequest("get", Method.GET) { Credentials = new NetworkCredential("testUser", "P455w0rd") };

            request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer qaPmk9Vw8o7r7UOiX-3b-8Z_6r3w0Iu2pecwJ3x7CngjPp2fN3c61Q_5VU3y0rc-vPpkTKuaOI2eRs3bMyA5ucKKzY1thMFoM0wjnReEYeMGyq3JfZ-OIko1if3NmIj79ZSpNotLL2734ts2jGBjw8-uUgKet7jQAaq-qf5aIDwzUo0bnGosEj_UkFxiJKXPPlF2L4iNJSlBqRYrhw08RK1SzB4tf18Airb80WVy1Kewx2NGq5zCC-SCzvJW-mlOtjIDBAQ5intqaRkwRaSyjJ_MagxJF_CLc4BNUYC3hC2ejQDoTE6HYMWMcg0mbyWghMFpOw3gqyfAGjr6LPJcIly__aJ5__iyt-BTkOnMpDAZLTjzx4qDHMPWeND-TlzKWXjVb5yMv5Q6Jg6UmETWbuxyTdvGTJFzanUg1HWzPr7gSs6GLEv9VDTMiC8a5sNcGyLcHBIJo8mErrZrIssHvbT8ZUPWtyJaujKvdgazqsrad9CO3iRsZWQJ3lpvdQwucCsyjoRVoj_mXYhz3JK3wfOjLff16Gy1NLbj4gmOhBBRb8rJnUXnP7rBHs00FAk59BIpKLIPIyMgYBApDCut8V55AgXtGs4MgFFiJKbuaKxq8cdMYEVBTzDJ-S1IR5d6eiTGusD5aFlUkAs9NV_nFw");
            request.AddParameter("clientId", 123);

            IRestResponse<RootObject> response = client.Execute<RootObject>(request);

            if (response.IsSuccessful)
            {
                response.Data.Write();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(response.ErrorMessage);
            }
```

Comment: I can't reproduce any problems.

Comment: hope the JSON string that API returns is a valid JSON format.

Comment: Add the stack trace

Comment: seems to be an invalid JSON string. you should have a look in the response you get

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in your code, but in the response coming from the API you are calling.
I had a similar issue with an old html page whose declaration was like

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
```

I changed the declaration to the well-known `<!DOCTYPE html>`, but since the HTML response is not yours, I think your only choice is to try other ways to parse the response and/or contact the owner.

What you can try, as a slightly different approach is using `System.Net.WebClient`:

```
System.Net.WebClient oWeb = new System.Net.WebClient();
oWeb.Proxy = System.Net.WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;
oWeb.Proxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
string response = "";
try
{
    byte[] responseBytes;
    NameValueCollection coll = new NameValueCollection();
    //if you need to add some headers the syntax is like: oWeb.Headers.Add("Content-Type","text/plain");
    responseBytes = oWeb.UploadValues(Url, "POST", coll);
    //I am using "POST" instead of "GET" but it shouldn't have conflict with your issue.
    response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseBytes);
    //then you can parse the response as string.
    ParseResponseAsString(response);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e);
}
```

Comment: That's a good find on the error type. Maybe add a line telling OP how they can find "other ways to parse the response" to help them a bit more?

Comment: @Joon - Good point. I added a possible alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Does the API have different possible response types?

Try adding

```
request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
```